# Java Swing - Making JFrame behave like a dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, swingx

I have a main frame and a attached collapsible panel that i got from http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/miasct/2009/03/29/external-collapsible-panel/.
The problem is collapsible panel creates undecorated frame that extends JFrame (actually JXFrame from SwingX) and behaves like one.

1. How do i get rid of this:

[image]

2. Dont show it in alt+tab thingy
3. When i use "minimize all windows" in WindowsOS and then maximize main frame, attached frame stays iconified.

Here's a code for it:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.WindowUtils;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;

import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXFrame;
import ui.MainFrame;



/**
 * CollapsibleFrame
 *
 * @author Devon Bryant
 * @since Mar 26, 2009
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CollapsibleFrame extends JXFrame implements ICollapsibleFrame
{
    // The parent frame to tie this frame to
    private JFrame parentFrame = null;

    // Orientation (where the collapsible frame is located relative to the parent frame)
    private Orientation orientation = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param inName the frame name
     * @param inParentFrame the parent frame to tie this frame to
     * @param the orientation (where in respect to the parent frame to attach to)
     */
    public CollapsibleFrame(String inName, JFrame inParentFrame, Orientation inOrientation)
    {
        super(inName);

        parentFrame = inParentFrame;
        orientation = inOrientation;
                setUndecorated(true);          
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mia.sct.view.panel.ICollapsibleFrame#relocate()
     */
    @Override
    public void relocate()
    {
        offset(0, 0);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mia.sct.view.panel.ICollapsibleFrame#offset(int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void offset(int inX, int inY)
    {
        if ((parentFrame != null && parentFrame.isVisible()))
        {
            Point p = null;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            // Calculate the new x,y coordinates for this frame based on the parents location
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case TOP:
                    p = parentFrame.getLocationOnScreen();
                    x = p.x;
                    y = p.y - getHeight();
                    break;

                case BOTTOM:
                    p = parentFrame.getLocationOnScreen();
                    x = p.x;
                    y = p.y + parentFrame.getHeight();
                    break;

                case LEFT:
                    p = parentFrame.getLocationOnScreen();
                    x = p.x - getWidth();
                    y = parentFrame.getContentPane().getLocationOnScreen().y;
                    break;

                case RIGHT:
                    p = parentFrame.getLocationOnScreen();
                    x = p.x + parentFrame.getWidth();
                    y = parentFrame.getContentPane().getLocationOnScreen().y;
                    break;
            }   
            x += inX;
            y += inY;

            // set the location of this frame
            setLocation(x, y);                     
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mia.sct.view.panel.ICollapsibleFrame#setMask(java.awt.Shape)
     */
    public void setMask(Shape inShape)
    {
        WindowUtils.setWindowMask(this, inShape);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mia.sct.view.panel.ICollapsibleFrame#setAlpha(float)
     */
    public void setAlpha(float inAlpha)
    {
        if (WindowUtils.isWindowAlphaSupported())
        {
            WindowUtils.setWindowAlpha(this, inAlpha);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not good idea hold two `JFrames` (or its SwingX derivates) in same time, you have to change that for Un-Decorated `JDialog` or `JWindow` (its SwingX derivates), that solving three issues and you can correctly to set

- `setParent`
- `setModal`, `ModalityTypes`
- no `iconified` in WinOS

Comment: thanks for response. You see the code comes from a link i provided. Maybe there's a reason for using Jframe? please check out code i added. Thanks.

Comment: another question, why did you mixing `javax.swing.JFrame;` with `org.jdesktop.swingx.JXFrame;`

Comment: Its not me, im just trying to make this code i've found work nicely. You mean JFrame parentFrame;? thats the "main frame". the one this whole thing is attached to.

Comment: You are totally right, non modal JXDialog works just fine but animation of closing became kinda choppy for some reason. Thank you!